# MVC alternative for PortalModuleBase.ControlPath?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

How can I access the ControlPath property for a module inside one of its views?
In a webforms module, the user control inherited from PortalModuleBase which provided the ControlPath. What is the MVC equivalent?

Comment: I assume you are looking for the path to where the root MVC module is stored in this case?  Its a bit different for MVC modules due to folder structures etc.  So just trying to be sure.

Comment: @MitchelSellers Yes, that's right. Something like <portalroot>\DesktopModules\MVC\ModuleFolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apeksha,

Sorry this is so late, but here is what I worked up...

In your MVC controller action:

```
ViewBag.ModulePath = $"~/DesktopModules/MVC/{ModuleContext.Configuration.DesktopModule.FolderName}";
```

Then in your razor view:

```
@{
    ClientResourceManager.RegisterStyleSheet(Dnn.DnnPage, ViewBag.ModulePath + "/Resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css");
}
```

If you need the server path, just add:

```
Server.MapPath(ViewBag.ModulePath);
```